# Remove jQuery from existing AngularJS project

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I try to remove jQuery from an existing AngularJS project.

The problem is that the mouse events does not work properly anymore.
But I don't get any errors in the Chrome console.

Does anybody knows what can cause this problem?

EDIT:
It seems that just the mousedown events are not fired anymore without jQuery. Very strange.

```
link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
    console.log("OK");
    element.on("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("MOUSEDOWN");
    });
}
```

If I remove `jquery.js` from my `index.html`, the code does not work anymore.

In another directive the following still works fine.

```
element.on("mousemove", function (e) {
    console.log("MOUSEMOVE");
});
```

Apparently the events work only in some directives.

My **only** change was to remove jquery.

Comment: can you show the code where you have used mouseevents?

Comment: If you remove some library that is used you're gonna see some strange results. Find all the places that jQuery is used and re-implement it without that library.

Comment: MouseDown is a native javascript function, however jquery changes the write mode